# Kubernetes CPU Manager configuration for real time workloads

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to configure our K8s cluster for real time workloads. Unfortunately, the Pods that are schedule are still running on the CPU cores that should only be used for the system (housekeeping cgroup).

I have set the following settings in the kubelet.conf:

```
cpuManagerPolicy: static
reservedSystemCPUs: 0,1,12,13
featureGates:
  CPUManager: true
  CPUManagerPolicyOptions: true
cpuManagerPolicyOptions:
  full-pcpus-only: "true"
```

When deploying pods I still see some processes from inside the Pod running on cores `0,1,12,13`.

The CPU Manager state file looks like this (when a Pod with QoS Guaranteed is deployed):

```
{"policyName":"static","defaultCpuSet":"0-1,11-13,23","entries":{"fc42685d-5ee6-43c6-b443-bdc97ce2a7ec":{"srs-app":"2-10,14-22"}},"checksum":457645317}
```

The requests:

```
"resources": {
    "requests": {
        "cpu": 18,
        "memory": "64G",
        "hugepages-1Gi": "2Gi",
        "ephemeral-storage": "9G"
    },
    "limits": {
        "cpu": 18,
        "memory": "64G",
        "hugepages-1Gi": "2Gi",
        "ephemeral-storage": "9G"
    },
```

I am running on a Dell XR12, Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5317 CPU @ 3.00GHz, 96GB RAM. The grub args I have applied are:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.0-1036-realtime root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro selinux=0 enforcing=0 nmi_watchdog=0 crashkernel=auto softlockup_panic=0 nosoftlockup audit=0 mce=off tsc=nowatchdog skew_tick=1 quiet splash intel_pstate=disable processor.max_cstate=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=0 hugepagesz=1G hugepages=16 hugepagesz=2M hugepages=0 default_hugepagesz=1G intel_iommu=on iommu=pt rcu_nocb_poll rcu_nocbs=2-11,14-23 nohz=on nohz_full=2-11,14-23 kthread_cpus=0,1,12,13 irqaffinity=0,1,12,13 nosoftlockup tsc=nowatchdog vt.handoff=7
```

I have not used the grub arg `isolcpus`. Is this necessary for this setup? Am I missing something else?

Thanks in advance!